# Getting Twitter auth token with Volley POST request

Tags: android, twitter, oauth-2.0, android-volley

I'm trying to produce a proper request for Twitter Application-only authorization token using a Volley POST request, but I keep getting a Http 400 response (Bad Request).

This is what I tried :

**URL**

```
private static final String TWITTER_API_AUTH_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
```

**Encoding the consumer key and the consumer secret**

```
try {
    byte[] data = (URLEncoder.encode(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8") + ":" + URLEncoder.encode(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8")).getBytes("UTF-8");
    mEncodedKeyAndSecret = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    //handleError
}
```

**Custom Volley StringRequest**

```
private class TokenRequestWithAuthHeader extends StringRequest{

    public TokenRequestWithAuthHeader (int method, String url, Response.Listener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Content-Length", String.valueOf(getBody().length));
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + mEncodedKeyAndSecret);
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        return ("grant_type=client_credentials").getBytes();
    }
}
```

**Sending Request**

```
tokenRequest = new TokenRequestWithAuthHeader 
                (Request.Method.POST, TWITTER_API_AUTH_URL,  mCallback.getTokenResponseListener(), mCallback);
requestQueue.add(tokenRequest);
```

[**Documentation about Application-Only authentication at dev.twitter.com**](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only)

I also tried extending `JsonObjectRequest` and `JsonRequest` instead of `StringRequest`, same result.

Can someone help identify what is the problem with the request ?

Comment: Did you get succesful responde when using some tools such as Postman?

Comment: I generated a request on www.hurl.it with the encoded Basic authentication header I printed out in LogCat after generating it from the same code I used above, using the same content type header, and got the expected 200 success response. I'm quite puzzled :)

Comment: If just for testing or learning, could you post TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY and TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET or the encoded Basic authentication header so that we can check?

Comment: Sure, here it is : Basic cjMzZXVWeG5ZSDN3NjJ1RUdhV1NtcDAzYzpDa0h5Q3N1ZXF5ZXVobTExWURnTmpKMUZWRFN6OEk5TDFXWXJVUTFQWTNPZTcxcWlGdQ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested with the credential you've provided in comments. It's working with the following logcat output (I truncated real access token's content)

```
I/onResponse: {"access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIwbjgAAAAAAGVMKCDU9taD0ke3sStAyA2WKszs%3DA4nfnpLTF31YuE.............JFtKjrTQC1K","token_type":"bearer"}
```

My code:

```
            final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            final String url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
            final String requestBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("onResponse", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("onErrorResponse", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    // Basic Authentication
                    //String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(CONSUMER_KEY_AND_SECRET.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    String auth = "Basic cjMzZXVWeG5ZSDN3NjJ1RUdhV1NtcDAzYzpDa0h5Q3N1ZXF5ZXVobTExWURnTmpKMUZWRFN6OEk5TDFXWXJVUTFQWTNPZTcxcWlGdQ==";
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try after eating !

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks again ! Stil not sure what was wrong with the JSONRequest implementation that I tried earlier, looks very similar. I'll post my findings here, if I ever make sense of this :)

Comment: `TokenRequestWithAuthHeader requestWithAuthHeader = new TokenRequestWithAuthHeader(1, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, error.toString());
            }
        });

        queue.add(requestWithAuthHeader);` works too :)

Comment: Finally got it : there were 2 small mistakes in my code, first I missing a space between `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; and `charset=UTF-8`, secondly I was using `Base64.DEFAULT` which was adding a space in the middle of the String (not sure why, I thought it was just LogCat doing that for readability), using `Base64.NO_WRAP` fixed the issue... Thanks again for helping out, and a happy new year to you !!

Comment: Glad to hear that, happy new year to you and your family too :)

Comment: Hi , I tried this but I am not able to send string "requestBody" as it needs jsonobject by default.

Comment: @NibhaJain looks like that your project uses Google's official volley lib? If you use it as a module instead of JAR file, you should add `public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
                             Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener,
                errorListener);
    }` into `JsonObjectRequest.java` file , or use mcxiaoke's lib which is deprecated (https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

Answer (score -1):

```
private void fetchAccessTokens() {
        final String requestBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

        JsonObjectRequest req1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                TwitterTokenURL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("Response: ", response.toString());

                        fetchTweets(response.toString());

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

                // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                String urlApiKey = null;
                String urlApiSecret = null;
                try {
                    urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                    urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                // encoded consumer secret
                String credentials = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                String auth = "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                return requestBody.getBytes();
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req1, tag_json_arry);

    }
```

Comment: Don't just post code, you need to explain how this answers the question the OP asked, maybe a bit about how it works, etc.